# How to detect when a winforms application creates a new window?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm using a webbrowser control in my form application and I want to block any popup/alert/prompt window that it can create.

Currently, I am implementing various methods to block popups like:

- Canceling various events that fire when a new window is created.
- Changing global IE settings through the registry to make it show less
  alerts and prompts.
- Using browser feature controls to block some popups.
- Injecting javascript into every page to disable functions that can create new windows.
- Extending the web browser control with new events by implementing things like IDocHostShowUI which allow me to
  block certain popups.
- Using the "hidden" events of the base activeX webbrowser object like NewWindow2 and NewWindow3.

All of this combined blocks 99% of all the windows that the webbrowser control can create (the 1% being some extremely rare cases like a javascript prompt() function called from within an iframe which document is located on a different domain than the parent window, still haven't found a way to block that :D).

But it's a lot of code, making it a big mess which can sometime interfere with normal browsing.
I want to know if there is a different approach. Since most of the windows that are created by the webbrowser control are actually created by my application's process, is there a way to detect when my application creates any kind of window that is not the main form and close it instantly or block it's creation entirely?

**UPDATE:**

I have tried overriding the WndProc method for the webbrowser control, but no messages are sent when a prompt appears.

When overriding it for the entire form, I do get some messages when a prompt appears, but they are related to losing focus and not to the actual creation of a prompt. So I am able to detect when a prompt is created, but still not able to block it's creation.

Comment: Been a while since I did any of this so I'm not answering.  But google WndProc, Window Subclassing, SetWindowHookEx, SetWindowLong, etc..  You will need to rewrite the web browsers WndProc callback to one of your own making, where you can intercept messages from the Web Brwoser control and let them through, or block them.

Comment: Optionally, you could junk the web browser control and use CEF (Chrome Embeded Framework) and probably have better features.  https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23+webbrowser+block+popup&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @Ryios I have tried overriding the WndProc method for the web browser, but I am not getting any messages when a prompt is created.

Comment: Hmm, it might not be possible then.  You might want to look at CEF as an alternative.  Well it's possible, but what you'll need to do is hook CreateWindow, which is pretty involved.  You'll need to use c/c++ to do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to close any window except the current one, you can use the code below inside the timer_tick event:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Application.OpenForms.Count; i++)
    {
        Form form = Application.OpenForms[i];
        if (form != this)
        {
            form.Close();
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It only closes form windows, and not other type of windows like dialog boxes. It would be great if something similar exists which could detect all types of windows.

Comment: I searched a little bit, but unfortunately I couldn't a way to close modal dialog boxes.